# Animate marker in Open layer map

Tags: angular, typescript, animation, openlayers-3

I have been trying to find a marker animation plugin for OpenLayers to sync lat, lon, and time data along a track like [this](http://leafletplayback.theoutpost.io/examples/example_2.html) (in Leaflet).

Basically, I want to draw a line string and animate the first marker till the tend with timeline slider with speed control. I have seen [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.htm), but it is confusing and doesn't meet my requirement. Looking for an easy sample example. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirements? Because from reading your question, I would have pointed you exactly to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/feature-move-animation.html.

Comment: http://leafletplayback.theoutpost.io/examples/example_2.html

Comment: That's quite different from what you describe in your question. Whereas that OpenLayers example is quite similar to your description.

Comment: I want to link the marker animation to a timeline slider to move back and forth during animation